# Microphone with combo-jack - Windows 10, Lenovo b580

Tags: audio, lenovo-laptop, microphone

I'm looking on answers how to solve this problem since I got this laptop. This is the newer version of lenovo b580 (the one with i3 mobile). It has a single combo-jack on the side, and I cannot get it to recognize my microphone (tried it in windows 7, 8, 8.1 and now at 10).

The audio card is:

```
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0269&SUBSYS_17AA500A&REV_1002
```

And the system identified it as Realtek High Definition Audio card. I can also see in the device manager two other devices - a nvidia one, and a "HDA Compliant Standard Device" (sorry if I translated this incorrectly):

```
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_8086&DEV_2806&SUBSYS_80860101&REV_1000
```

And a nvidia audio device (probably related to my Nvidia Optimus setup):

```
USB\VID_0955&PID_9000
```

In the recording devices tab i see:

[image: Recording audio devices]

The bottom one seems to be my laptop built-in microphone (based on trial-and-combat with woobling my finger against it). The top one seems to be what SHOULD be my combo-jack, but it keeps saying "Not connected" (the bottom one was disabled by me, for some tests, turning it on doesn't change a thing).

I've found some forum posts that told me I should be prompted for a 'connected device type' from realtek, but I have never been. There is also no option in the realtek control center to enable the mic, or to change the device type. This is all I see in realtek audio manager:

[image]

Uff, that's a lot of information. The question is: how the hell can I get this to work?

I do own a kind of "splitter" that looks like this: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Displays-Options-and-Accessories/Microphone-Headset-Jack-splitter-needed-for-combo/ta-p/256059 but just connecting this doesn't do the trick. There has to be something wrong with the configuration/drivers.

Comment: I have started this bounty because this issue bugs me for almost 3 years now, since I bought this notebook. I know that combo-jacks are common problem-makers, but this is exactly what they are designed for.

Comment: does the jack work for sound output, like for a headphone?

Comment: I do not know about your laptop and your problem, but I had a lot of trouble with Win 10 and the realtek drivers.  In this [forum](http://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/5993-latest-realtek-hd-audio-driver-version.html) they post links to the latest relatek drivers provided on some microsoft site, newer than on the realtek site itself or through Windows Update.  My problem was solved by using the latest driver from this thread.

Comment: @Chin: Yes it does, the audio output works fine.

Comment: @Martin: I will try your solution in a few hours, when I get home from work. I'll let you guys know if this worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the Windows 10 equivalent drivers are not allowing the proper drivers to install and take precedent.  Lets start with the following steps to correct this:

1. To ensure changes to the driver do not occur without your knowledge, open the Control Panel (right-click Start button and select Control Panel)
2. Navigate to System and Security > System > Advanced system settings
3. Click Hardware tab > Device Installation Settings and select No, let me choose what to do option
4. Select Never install driver software from Windows Update
5. Next. Press the Windows key‌ Windows logo key+X and choose Device Manager.
6. In Device Manager, navigate to Sound, video and game controllers
7. Right click on Realtek or IDT High Definition Audio and choose uninstall
8. Ensure the delete the driver software for this device is checked
9. Download and install the following audio driver: http://support.lenovo.com/gb/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-b-series-laptops/lenovo-b580-notebook/4377?tabName=Downloads
10. Reboot the computer on installation completion.

This should resolve your Microphone / Audio issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, but these drivers are not meant to be used with my hardware. During the installation I get an error that no devices were found that are compatible with these drivers.

Comment: A little follow-up though: when I uninstalled the device it came back up with a "Generic audio driver". Microphone started working then, but with very poor quality. Now I don't know if it's the drivers fault, or is the jack faulty.

Comment: I think you may also require the Intel Chipset update for Windows 10 as well as the proper Audio.  Both drivers required can be found here: http://support.lenovo.com/gb/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-b-series-laptops/lenovo-b580-notebook/4377?tabName=Downloads

Comment: I will also try this within a few hours, thanks ;)

Comment: This also has no effect, sorry.

Comment: The bounty time expires soon, and no answer has provided me with a working combo jack yet, too bad for me. 

I choose  to give the bounty to this answer, however, because for a split moment the microphone AND audio was working (only the recorded sound quality was very, very poor), making this answer the closest one to  a working solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

There are [two different headset connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_%28audio%29#TRRS_standards) and they are not compatible. but unfortunately, AFAIK, Lenovo uses both. So instead of messing with drivers, you may want to try another headset.

Comment: I tried many different connections, including all mobile-headsets that I own, always with the same effect (only audio output detected, no audio input detected).

Is there any way to check the type of connector I have? I tried searching for the technical manual, but it only states that there is a 'Combo audio jack', nothing more about the model and/or standard.